# how to edit the saved graph by matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, edit

Thank you for reading this post.
I would like to load saved plot (graph) drawn by matplotlib and edit in python to resize it.
Is there anyway how to do this?
Simply becuase the subtitle of one graph and x_ticks were overlapped and looks uggly.
Please help me out.
[image]
Thanks.
Sincerely,
SANGWOO SON.

Comment: If you saved this graph as an image already, then there is no way you can import this and then resize and save it back, since the graph is converted to an image now. You need to draw/create this graph and then save it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by Arjun Muraleedharan, once you save your plot in Matplotlib, you will not be able to modify it.

However, if your problem is with the axes overlapping in the image, then try `plt.tight_layout()`. Call this just before your `plt.show()` in your code, assuming you did `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

What it does is it prevents any overlapping of anything in your plots and makes everything look a lot neater, which (I think) is what you are looking for.